# str_ireplace() not replaces only the last match

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the urls of a web page. I am using DOM to get all the links in the page, loop through the links and find and replace one by one using str_ireplace.
The str_ireplace replaces only the last link. When I count, it gives proper count of the number of links to be replaced, but does not replace the links.

```
    $contents=file_get_contents($_GET['page']);
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($contents);    
    $links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
$c=0;
//Iterate over the extracted links and display their URLs
    foreach ($links as $link){
        //echo $link->nodeValue;
        $arr['retUrl']=$link->getAttribute('href');
        $xyz=json_encode($arr);
        $rurl=$base_url.'?ret_url='.urlencode($xyz);
        echo $arr['retUrl'].'<br>'.$rurl.'<br><br><br>';

        $x=str_ireplace($link->getAttribute('href'),$rurl,$contents,$count);
        $c=$c+$count;
        echo '--'.$count.'--';
    }

    echo $x;
```

Comment: var_dump($links); figure out the correct array hierarchy and then rewrite your iterator. Then, change $x=str_ireplace to $x .= str_ireplace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you output `$x`, and what is `$x`? It is `$contents` with **last** `$link` processed. I'm sure you need to save all previous replacements in `$contents` too. Replace

```
$x=str_ireplace($link->getAttribute('href'),$rurl,$contents,$count);
```

with

```
$contents = str_ireplace($link->getAttribute('href'),$rurl,$contents,$count);
```

Here you **overwrite** `$contents` with every replaced link. After loop - output `$contents`.

Comment: Why would you set $content = to anything, when he never uses the variable $content to begin with. It is nowhere in his scope.

Comment: Still wrong. You're making the operation with $contents the same thing as his use of $x.

You should do $contents .= to append the updated content to the string. And even still THAT would be wrong because he already set $contents earlier in the scope, which would append to what has already been established directly from the file I/O to begin with.

Comment: Nope. Every loop `$x` is a __new__ value that is not used anywhere. So, I overwrite everylink in `$contents` and save this overwritten text to `$contents` again. As for you solution - you will append `$contents` to previously replaced `$contents`. But I suppose you're too clever to understand it.

Comment: WHY in the world would you reuse $contents inside the scope of an interator when it exists outside that scope? What is the purpose of that?

Comment: The value of $contents at the end of your poor example would STILL only contain one link.

Comment: Undefined variable $x. Not my code. It was the OP's. @u_mulder failed to show he could solve it.

Comment: @Penguine make sure you don't mix `$contents` and `$content` and `$x`. According to sample example everything should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looking over it, change it to this:

```
   $x .= str_ireplace($link->getAttribute('href'),$rurl,$contents,$count);
```

Comment: Same output. Nothing Changes

Comment: Does it have something to do with the url format? I mean special characters. The urls which it shud replace is of this type: http://www.example.com/tieups/tieups.php?encuser=~$encUserName`;&amp;othersrcp=2988543

Comment: No, once they are in string, they are in string.

Comment: Your var_dump should have shown you a large array with every link in it, if it didnt, that's an issue.

Comment: But this line: echo $arr['retUrl'].'<br>'.$rurl.'<br><br><br>'; prints all the urls that are supposed to be replaced. Hence I dont think there is any issue with $links

Comment: So then your URL's are not being parsed. $arr['retUrl'] is only ONE element in the array.

Comment: Your var_dump shows only one item in the array: object(DOMNodeList)#2 (1) { ["length"]=> int(12) }

Comment: That one item could be a hierarchical item, so try this... var_dump($arr[0]), see what happens.

Comment: No, its printing all the links(which are obviously different), when echoded inside the foreach loop

Comment: What if you $x .= str_ireplace($arr['retUrl'],$rurl,$contents,$count);

Comment: Same. No changes

Comment: Something bigger is wrong, i'm sorry I can't help without seeing more. My account will be deleted in 24 hours due to me being tired of trolls on this site. Good luck with your project.

Comment: No problem, var_dump each piece step by step and you'll find your answer soon. I promise.

Comment: surely, ill do that

Comment: @Matth3w your answer is not at all correct, as the `$x` will contain the value of `$contents` many time over instead of actually updating all the urls in block it will have some urls updated in each block. Check my answer, to see where you went wrong.